# Как отсортировать массив продуктов по отдельному полю(поля: имя, количество, цена за штуку). Ошибка компиляции

Tags: java

//    Использую алгоритм бульбашки но видаєш ошибку в методе: public void sortQuantity

package com.company.prodacts_v3;

```
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    public Product() {
        this.quantity = 1;
        this.price = 1;
    }


    public Product(String name, int quantity, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    private final String format = "%s. Quantity = %,d. One bottle = %,.3f$\n";

    public double getPriceTypeProduct() {
        double costOfAlcoholOrder = getQuantity() * getPrice();
        return costOfAlcoholOrder;
    }

    public void showInfo() {
        System.out.printf(format, getName(), getQuantity(), getPrice());
    }
    public void showPriceTypeProduct() {
        System.out.printf("\t\tPrice = %,.3f$\n", getPriceTypeProduct());
    }
}



package com.company.prodacts_v3;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Product[] products = new Product[5];
        products[0] = new Product("Beer", 12, 45.55);
        products[1] = new Product("Vodka", 16, 5.23);
        products[2] = new Product("Vine", 18, 8.12);
        products[3] = new Product("Beer-1", 2, 9.85);
        products[4] = new Product("Beer-2", 42, 125.55);

        for(int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            products[i].showInfo();
            products[i].showPriceTypeProduct();
        }
    sortQuantity(products);




// Ето пример алгоритма:
        int[] arr = {2, -5, 7, -4, 8};
        int tmp ;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
                    tmp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }

    }// Ето пример алгоритма


    public static void sortQuantity(Product[] products) {
        int quantitys = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < products.length; j++) {
                if(products[i].getQuantity() < products[j].getQuantity()) {
                    quantitys = products[i].getQuantity();
                    products[i].getQuantity() = products[j].getQuantity();  // Error! 
                    products[j].getQuantity() = quantitys;  // Error!
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(products[i].getQuantity());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Что за ошибка ?

Comment: products[i].getQuantity() = products[j].getQuantity();  // Error! не воспринимает левую часть данного виражения

Comment: Error:(41, 44) java: unexpected type
  required: variable
  found:    value

Comment: Вам нужно менять обьекты местами, а не значение возвращаемые методами. С джавой не работал но по идее должно быть что-то вроде products[i] = products[j]; а не products[i].getQuantity() = products[j].getQuantity();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем сортировать вручную, если Java умеет это делать за вас?
Вот пример сортировки товаров по их количеству.

```
public static void sortQuantity(Product[] products) {
  products = Arrays.stream(products)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Product::getQuantity))
    .toArray(Product[]::new);

  for(int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(products[i].getQuantity());
  }
}
```

Comment: я учусь, и задача стоит как посортировать вручну. Спасибо за такой вариант ответа